# Unix set date without touching timestamp

Tags: date, unix, unix-timestamp

I want to set system date to different date for testing.
But, I want to revert the date to correct date + time after testing.

So, I wonder if there is a way to set only the date without touching the timestamp.

Or, if that is not possible. How can I set the date back to correct date + time easily after testing?

Comment: Its not clear what exactly you are looking for. How are you setting env date?

Comment: you can use "date"(a command) to set the system date from command line in Unix. just like you can change you date on your windows from the right bottom conner, right?